# JBoss as RMI client

Tags: java, jboss, rmi

I have JBoss 4.2.3 running on one machine and I want to call an RMI client.  On another machine I have an RMI server running.  Both are using port 1099 to communicate.  I was able to get both set up and running after a lot of configuration headaches and reading about Java's security policies.  However, when I try and actually call a remote method from within a war file that I deployed inside of JBoss, I get the following error:

```
2012-03-20 17:22:29,402 ERROR -> (http-8443-25) [com.mvs.services] non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

How do I overcome this error?

Comment: Did you get that on the `lookup()` or the remote method call?

Comment: I get that on the remote call.  Lookup works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you are connecting to http-8443 port which is HTTP over SSL. Are you sure you are connecting to 1099? If yes, maybe you have to use secure invocation (i.e. SSL).

This is a guess purely based on the error message and I could be way off.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I am connecting to my JBoss over HTTPS.  My desired functionality is client -> JBoss server -> RMI server.  Connection 1 is done over port 8443.  I'm trying to get connection 2 done over port 1099 (or any port for that matter).  Do I need to configure RMI to be done over SSL?  What else am I missing?

Comment: How are you connecting to JBoss? Is your client RMI client connecting to JBoss? Is this error related to connection 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm connecting to JBoss over HTTPS which is working fine.  Connection 1 is happening fine, and has nothing to do with RMI.  Connection 2 is failing, and is the one I'm trying to do over RMI.

Comment: It looks like the traffic is still secure when you are making the second connection. Maybe you'll need to secure RMI as well but I can't be sure.

Comment: How do I do that?  Is there any more information I can provide to help you make a decision?